# I need to match a specific part of text and get the following numbers out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I have a a div which contains mixed text (symbols, numbers, text etc) and I want to grab the numbers after matching a particular part.

For example:

Within the text is a part which says 'StartTime=' and this is followed by a timestamp which is what I need to get.

```
"EndTime=Fri, 23 Sep 2016 01:37:26 UTC client area:v2.1.2 
 operation = successful Time=9910 ms StartTime=1474594636638 
 client prod name EndTime=Fri, 23 Sep 2016 01:37:26 UTC client 
 area:v2.1.2 operation = successful Time=9910 ms"
```

out of the text above, I need to get this number out '1474594636638'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a regex

```
var numb = text.match(/StartTime=(.*?)\s/)[1];
```

or just split

```
var numb = text.split('StartTime=').pop().split(' ').shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the substring of the part you need:

```js
var string = "EndTime=Fri, 23 Sep 2016 01:37:26 UTC client area:v2.1.2 operation = successful Time=9910 ms StartTime=1474594636638 client prod name EndTime=Fri, 23 Sep 2016 01:37:26 UTC client area:v2.1.2 operation = successful Time=9910 ms";
 
 var startTime = string.substring(string.indexOf('StartTime='), string.indexOf(' client prod name')).replace('StartTime=', '');
 
 console.log(startTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael however, the index might change.

Comment: How? is the string not going to be always the same?? If the timestamp is always going to be after 'StartTime=' and before 'client prod name'?

Comment: You should try the code snippet I provided you. The code will find the index, it doesn't matter if it changes, it will get the index. Hope that helps.

Comment: Apologies, it's my fault. The text will index be 'startTime=' however, the end ' client prod name' will most likely change